# Separate editors for date and time of one property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, date, datetime, razor, datepicker

I have a Date field in my model. Date format is "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm" and I have no idea how to implement proper datetime picker. 
Is it possible to create two inputs: one for date part and one for time and bind them to one Date field? 
Or the only way is to use two fields (Datetime "dd.mm.yyyy" and TimeSpan "hh:mm")?

Comment: Not without using javascript. You could look at using a jquery datetime plugin, for example [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Is this a personal challenge, or can you opt for a commercial control library? If something you want to do yourself: using a single text input field, with client-side plugin code, would be your best bet. It means writing a plugin (jQuery/Javascript) that converts it into multiple controls at run-time, but certainly doable. I just had to write a custom picker for date-ranges (start and end dates pickers from a single input field) that does this sort of thing. As you are a .Net man, I would recommend using jQuery with TypeScript.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Unfortunately, I'm new to javascript, that's why I'm finding a way to implement it without writing my own script.. I thought this task has more simple solution. Thank you anyway, I'll try this!